# Is it secure to use Json files as db in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, json, next.js

I'm trying to create a video app that has free and premium videos. There will be around 100 videos in total so I don't think I need a database to store video links. I wonder if it's secure to read them from a json file. Are files created in src folder accessible to users?

videos.json

```js
{
  "introduction": "sd324d",
  "how-to-save-money": "824ds",
  "invesments": "64hdxc",
  "do-it-yourself": "82jxcn",
  "final-project": "hd82hd",
}
```

video API

```js
export default async function handler(req,res) {
  const { videoSlug } = req.query;
  const isUserPremim = // Take the token and check user

  if(!isUserPremim) return res.status(403).json("Not allowed!")

  const jsonDirectory = path.join(
    process.cwd(),
    `/src/content/videos.json`
  );
  const fileContents = await fs.readFile(jsonDirectory, "utf8");
  const objectData = JSON.parse(fileContents);

  const id = objectData[videoSlug];
  return res.status(200).json(id);
}
```

Code works as expected. I just worried about the data security. I plan to deploy it on Vercel.

Comment: Typically nextjs only makes files under the `public` folder accessible from the frontend. So if your json file is not in the public folder it won't be accessible from the frontend. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it because it's not hard to access your files. If you really want to you can make a node.js server which allows you to not show any files to users.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by saying "It's not hard to access your files". How to access it even if it's in the src folder?

Comment: @DaffyDuck if your security isn't very good people could do 'fetch('yourUrl/src/content/videos.json')' i recommend using a real database like  firebase which is much better.

Comment: @goAT2160 typically `yourUrl/src/...` is not exposed ie, i cannot be fetched from the frontend ...

Comment: @derpirscher yes but what i'm saying is that it's still more secure to have a real database like firebase which also comes with an authentication system

Comment: @goAT2160 Why? If a file cannot be fetched from the frontend it's irrelevant if it's a file or a database, or if there is authentication or not ...